# How to navigate the screen using arrow keys in Flex 4.6 AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a multipage, multiview flex application. Each page has a unique layout of buttons, circles, textfields, labels, datagrid, etc. I have to implement keyboard navigation on these pages. Instead of using Tabs to navigate to next enabled controls, I want to use Left, Right, Up, Down keys. How can I convert normal Tab navigation to Arrow navigation.

PS. I am new to AS3 and Flex.

Answer (score 0):

You should build a method in order to catch the events of the Keyboard and then use some variables to indicate where to put the Focus:

```
object.setFocus();
```